# How to create a singleton in Python that always replaces the previous instance?

Tags: python, singleton, finite-state-automaton

I'm working on a game in `pygame-ce` as a hobby, for scene management I've implemented a finite state machine. The problem is, it currently only kind of works, as the scene object is not garbage collected and then `reinitialized` in between "state flips". Which results in attributes not being reset etc. The most elegant way to deal with this is (imo) to define the scene class as a singleton, except that it doesn't keep a new instance from being created and instead always replaces the previous instance.

The idea would be something along these lines, meant as pseudo code:

```
class MySpecialSingleton:
instance = [0]
    def __init__(self):
        instance[0] = MySpecialSingleton.__init__
```

So basically when `MainMenu(MySpecialSingleton)` is created, `Splashscreen(MySpecialSingleton)` is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be best off adding a function to that class to forcibly create a new instance of your singleton.

Something along the lines of:

```python
class ReplaceableSingleton(object):
  _instance: "ReplaceableSingleton" = None

  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if (cls._instance is None):
      # only create it if it doesn't exist
      cls._instance = super(ReplaceableSingleton, cls).__new__(cls)
      # initialisation code here
    return cls._instance

  @classmethod
  def instance (cls):
    return cls._instance

  @classmethod
  def replace(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    this method gets gets rid of existing instance + replaces it
    :returns: new initialised instance
    """
    cls._instance = None # we can now make a new one
    return ReplaceableSingleton(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you ever want to get rid of the existing instance, just call `ReplaceableSingleton.replace()` and then a new instance will replace the old one.

However, you need to remember that **existing references to the old singleton object will still reference that object**.